# Broken “Install macOS Catalina” file

Tags: terminal, catalina, file

for some reason there exist this file in my desktop

[image]

When I move it to the bin and try to empty I get this message:

[image]

I have also tryied using the terminal:

```
sudo rm -rf Install\ macOS\ Catalina.app/
```

But when I do that I get:

```
rm: Install macOS Catalina.app/Contents/Frameworks/OSInstallerSetup.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/IAESD.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/IAOSPersonalization.framework/Versions/A/_CodeSignature: Directory not empty
rm: Install macOS Catalina.app/Contents/Frameworks/OSInstallerSetup.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/IAESD.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/IAOSPersonalization.framework/Versions/A: Directory not empty
rm: Install macOS Catalina.app/Contents/Frameworks/OSInstallerSetup.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/IAESD.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/IAOSPersonalization.framework/Versions: Directory not empty
rm: Install macOS Catalina.app/Contents/Frameworks/OSInstallerSetup.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/IAESD.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/IAOSPersonalization.framework: Directory not empty
rm: Install macOS Catalina.app/Contents/Frameworks/OSInstallerSetup.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/IAESD.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/IAPackageKit.framework: Directory not empty
rm: Install macOS Catalina.app/Contents/Frameworks/OSInstallerSetup.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/IAESD.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks: Directory not empty
rm: Install macOS Catalina.app/Contents/Frameworks/OSInstallerSetup.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/IAESD.framework/Versions/A: Directory not empty
rm: Install macOS Catalina.app/Contents/Frameworks/OSInstallerSetup.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/IAESD.framework/Versions: Directory not empty
rm: Install macOS Catalina.app/Contents/Frameworks/OSInstallerSetup.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/IAESD.framework: Directory not empty
rm: Install macOS Catalina.app/Contents/Frameworks/OSInstallerSetup.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks: Directory not empty
rm: Install macOS Catalina.app/Contents/Frameworks/OSInstallerSetup.framework/Versions/A: Directory not empty
rm: Install macOS Catalina.app/Contents/Frameworks/OSInstallerSetup.framework/Versions: Directory not empty
rm: Install macOS Catalina.app/Contents/Frameworks/OSInstallerSetup.framework: Directory not empty
rm: Install macOS Catalina.app/Contents/Frameworks: Directory not empty
rm: Install macOS Catalina.app/Contents: Directory not empty
rm: Install macOS Catalina.app: Directory not empty
```

Comment: Did you reboot yet?

Comment: Yes, I have rebooted my laptop many times.
The files seem to be broken.

Comment: Will it move to another folder, or even another drive?

Comment: I can move it to another folder, but not to an external drive (I can only copy it to an external drive)

Answer (score 1):

I moved the file to `/tmp`.

It was originally in `/Applications/Install macOS Catalina.app` so with Finder I opened `/Applications`, *Right click* `New Terminal at Folder` and ran from the Terminal:

```
mv Install\ macOS\ Catalina.app /tmp/
```

then Reboot. This rebooting took longer then expected but in the end the file was gone ... which is obvious as `/tmp` is emptied on reboot.